# Force timeout SQL Oracle on users response

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL procedure which has a couple prompts which require the user to enter some information for processing. For example, item numbers, business units & so on.

[image]

This as well prompts confirmation **at the end of the script**.

[image]

This allows several users to rely on the same script to massively setup data for testing (projects & so...). However, there are some certainly couldn't-care-less users that would leave the COMMIT confirmation prompt open, thus locking the record & preventing other users from working.

When we go to the users that has the record locked (we can only identify them with help of a DBA Team, which takes a lot of time), we ask them to close their tabs, & it always shows:

[image]

Is there a way to force a timeout (via the same SQL script) when a specific timelapse goes, which would call my WHENEVER SQLERROR handler for automatic rollback?

Comment: how is this locking anything at this point?  your app is just prompting for variable entry. Why do you think there is a lock going on?  Please show that.

Comment: You need to take the substitution values at starting of the procedure before you do any DML operation so nothing is locked before taking input for substitution variable

Comment: PL/SQL runs entirely within the database and has no ability to 'prompt for input'.  It looks to me as if you are calling the procedure from Toad. It would be Toad that is doing the prompting, and it would be doing that based on the specs of the procedure, before even calling the procedure.  Thus, there can be no locking from waiting on response.

Comment: I don't have permissions to retrieve locks' list, but when they execute a query (usually not this one) & they don't COMMIT it locks the record. I'm adding one of the ways we identify someone didn't complete their transactions. I think I missed to state that it's the prompt for commit or rollback the one I need to set a timeout for.

Comment: That is completely a function of TOAD.  why not ask for the commit prompt variable up front with the other input parameters?

Comment: Oh, because there is a high chance that the users are not satisfied with the result (they break something, got a wrong parameter or confuse IDs). We are using the same inbound file (to take advantage of Pristine processes) & they depend on each other. At the end I show in the output what they did: if they notice something they entered wrongly, they just rollback & try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to limit the `IDLE_TIME` of the users to a short time. I've used 1 minute for the demonstration:

```
CREATE PROFILE couldntcareless LIMIT IDLE_TIME 1;
ALTER USER xxx PROFILE couldntcareless;
```

If the user is now idle for longer than a minute, the changes are rolled back and it's session is killed.

Social hint: I assume you won't make any friends with this feature. I normally indentify the offending users by a look in the database, contact them and tell them that they do block the work of colleagues. Usually they were not aware of the fact, are quite embarrased and tend to improve their behaviour. If you don't have permission to `v$locked_object`, speak to a DBA to create a view that filters out your table(s) and make this view available to you.

Technical hint: The system parameter `RESOURCE_LIMIT` must be set to enfource those limits, aparently directly in the PDB, and you might have to restart the database:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_LIMIT=TRUE SCOPE=BOTH;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I just found out I've no privileges to CREATE or ALTER profiles.

Comment: Yes, that's a traditional task for the DBA team. Usually they are quite easy to persuade to create a special profile that limits CPU or idle time, especially as it saves them work (you wrote "we can only identify them with help of a DBA Team, which takes a lot of time"). So you have an nearly ideal point to argue "please create a profile or are more responsive to identify the nonresponsive users" :-)